# Wordpress $wpdb->get_results returning null

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get values using the below code but shows null values. I checked the database and it contains all data but not able to retrieve the data. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<?php
                global $wpdb;
                $q="SELECT data_id, value, name,
                MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'your-name' THEN value END) AS Name,
                MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'your-lastname' THEN value END) AS Lname,
                MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'your-city' THEN value END) AS City,
                MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'your-country' THEN value END) AS Country,
                MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'your-category' THEN value END) AS Category,
                MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'checkbox' THEN value END) AS Paid
                FROM wp_players_cf7_vdata_entry
                GROUP BY data_id
                HAVING Category LIKE 'Senior'
                ORDER BY FIELD(value, 'Paid') ,Paid DESC

                LIMIT 99";
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($q);

                var_dump($results);

                ?>
```

Comment: Have you run this query directly in phpmyadmin ? May be your query is returning false.

Comment: No, I did not run in phpmyadmin. Can you tell me where I have done wrong? @Jasbir

Comment: Check max cases 1 by 1..

Comment: @Jasbir I tried checking 1 by 1 but no result found.